# How to fail the chain if it's sub task gives an exception

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have faced a pretty strange issue with celery:

There is a chain of tasks, and one of them gives an exception and does several retries

```
chain = (err.si(1) | err.si(2))
result = chain.apply_async()
result.state
result.get()
```

here is the code of the task:

```
@celery.task(base=MyTask)
def err(x):
try:
    if x < 3:
        raise Exception
    else:
        return x+1

except Exception as exp:
    print "retrying"
    raise err.retry(args=[x],exc=exp,countdown=5,max_retries=3)
```

The thing is that although the task in chain gives an exception, but the result.state keeps being 'PENDING' and .get() just freezes.

I have tried to fail the task in case it reaches maximum retries value:

```
class MyTask(celery.Task):
abstract = True
def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
    if self.max_retries == self.request.retries:
        self.state = states.FAILURE
```

But although executed separately task is getting marked as FAILED, executing in chain gives same result - PENDING & Freezed get.

I expected that the chain will get failed once any of it's tasks will get failed and .get of the result should produce the exception thrown from the task.

_***UPDATE*_**
Stack trace given by apply_async with ALWAYS_EAGER=True

```
result = chain.apply_async()

Exception                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-81202b369b5f> in <module>()
----> 1 result = chain.apply_async()

lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.pyc in apply_async(self, args, kwargs,     **options)
    147         # For callbacks: extra args are prepended to the stored args.
    148         args, kwargs, options = self._merge(args, kwargs, options)
--> 149         return self.type.apply_async(args, kwargs, **options)
    150 
    151     def append_to_list_option(self, key, value):

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/builtins.pyc in apply_async(self, args, kwargs, group_id, chord, task_id, **options)
    232                 task_id=None, **options):
    233             if self.app.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER:
--> 234                 return self.apply(args, kwargs, **options)
    235             options.pop('publisher', None)
    236             tasks, results = self.prepare_steps(args, kwargs['tasks'])

lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/builtins.pyc in apply(self, args, kwargs, subtask, **options)
    249             last, fargs = None, args  # fargs passed to first task only
    250             for task in kwargs['tasks']:
--> 251                 res = subtask(task).clone(fargs).apply(last and (last.get(), ))
    252                 res.parent, last, fargs = last, res, None
    253             return last

lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.pyc in get(self, timeout, propagate, **kwargs)
    677         elif self.state in states.PROPAGATE_STATES:
    678             if propagate:
--> 679                 raise self.result
    680             return self.result
    681     wait = get

Exception:
```

Comment: Try running your  task with CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER activated , that should help you find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: In case I have CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER set to True, apply_async immediately gives the stack trace and the results var is None. In case I have it set to false, the result does exist with result.state = Pending.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you have a chain:

```
>>> c = a.s() | b.s() | c.s()
>>> res = c()
>>> res.get()
```

Calling the chain will generate unique id's for all of the task in the chain, send the messages and return the *last result in the chain*.

So when you do `res.get()` you are simple trying to retrieve the result of the last task in the chain.

It will also decorate the results with `parent` attributes, which you can traverse to get the progress of the chain:

```
>>> res                # result of c.s()
>>> res.parent         # result of b.s()
>>> res.parent.parent  # result of a.s()
```

If you want to check for errors along the way you can do:

```
def nodes(node):
    while node.parent:
        yield node
        node = node.parent
    yield node


values = [node.get(timeout=1) for node in reversed(list(nodes(res)))]
value = values[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for a great reply asksol!
Is there any conventional way to prevent child tasks from executing at all in case if any of its parents got failed (raised an exception)?
Example setup:
chord(group(parent1, parent2), group(children))
If parent1 fails, it's children executed with [exception, parent2.retval] as first argument, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Only chord works this way by passing along the exception value, and this behavior is not specified in the documentation.  I think it would make sense to make it consistent with the rest by not executing the chord callback instead. Maybe you could open an issue here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you shouldn't be using `raise` here.

You're throwing an exception, when the [documentation says you shouldn't](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/task-retries.html), you might want to just use `err.retry` and not `raise err.retry`.

Comment: This documentations is old.  Task.retry actually always raises an exception.  The exception is handled specially in the worker so it knows the task will be retried.  It makes the code harder to read when people don't know that it will raise, and think the code will continue below.  So the docs was changed to use 'raise err.retry' instead.  You don't need the raise, but it gives a hint to readers that it won't continue.

Comment: Technically this is a synthetic test, I want to handle exceptions there which may happen. My tasks interacting with external webservices which are unstable and may return unexpected output