# Celery chain monitoring: the easy way

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Using django-celery-3.0.17, celery-3.0.21 and django-1.5.1, I'm trying to monitor a chain execution.
I found a solution but it seems a little bit weird to me, so I'm searching for an easier solution if possible. Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
def runCod(request):
    runFunTask = runFunctions.delay(shpId, codId, stepValues, bboxTuple);
    getRunFunStatus.delay(runFunTask)
    return render_to_response('tss/append_runCod.html',
                             {'runFunTask': runFunTask},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def getProgressCod(request):
    task = AsyncResult(taskId)
    currStep = task.result['step']
    totSteps = task.result['total']

    if task.status == 'SUCCESS':
        task.revoke() # Manually terminate the runFunctions task

    response = dumps({'status':task.status,'currStep':currStep,'totSteps':totSteps})
    return HttpResponse(response, mimetype='application/json')
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task()
def runFunctions(shpId, codId, stepValues, bboxTuple):
    # ... Code to define which functions to launch ...

    stepsToLaunch = [fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4, fun5]
    chainId = chain(stepsToLaunch).apply_async()
    chainAsyncObjects = [node for node in reversed(list(nodes(chainId)))]

    current_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={'step':1, 'total':numSteps})

    for t in range(10800): # The same max duration of a celery task
        for i, step in enumerate(chainAsyncObjects):
            currStep = i+1
            if step.state == 'PENDING':
                current_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={'step':currStep, 'total':numSteps})
                break
            if step.state == 'SUCCESS':
                if currStep == numSteps:
                    current_task.update_state(state="SUCCESS", meta={'step':currStep, 'total':numSteps})
                    # This task will be terminated (revoked) by getProgressCod()
            if step.state == 'FAILURE':
                return
    sleep(1)
```

**cods.js**

```
function getProgressCod(taskId){
    var aoiStatus, allStatus, currStep, totSteps;
    var interval = 2000; // Perform ajax call every tot milliseconds

    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'getProgressCod/',
            data:{'taskId': taskId,},
            success: function(response){},
        });
    }, interval);
}
```

This is what's happening:

1. `runCod()` launches the async task `runFunctions()`;
2. `runFunctions()` creates and launches a chain of subtasks
3. With `runFunctions()` final loop I update every second its own 'PROGRESS' status looking at the single chain subtask status. (reference [1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660994/how-to-fail-the-chain-if-its-sub-task-gives-an-exception))
4. To know what's happening, the user is informed by `getProgressCod()` javascript function, which makes every 2 seconds an ajax request to `getProcessCod()` python function
5. `getProcessCod()` python function looks at `runFunctions()` status, and when it is 'SUCCESS', it revokes (terminate) the `runFunctions()` execution.

I did not find another way, because if I return `runFunctions()` when every subtask of the chain is done inside of its final loop, I cannot notify to the user its 'SUCCESS' status to the user because `getProcessCod()` will get a `None` object performing `task.status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved deleting `getProgressCod()` py function and inserting an if statement inside `runCod()`.
In this way I can monitor `runFunctions()` using `runCod()` and when it is succesfully terminated, I wait 5 seconds to get the result and then I close the task with a return.
My only remaining doubt is that if this waiting approach is it correct or not...
Here's my modified code:

**views.py**

```
def runCod(request):
    taskId = request.GET['taskId']
    if taskId != '': # If the task is already running
        task = AsyncResult(taskId)
        currStep = task.result['step']
        totSteps = task.result['total']
        response = dumps({'status':task.status,
                          'currStep':currStep,
                          'totSteps':totSteps})
        return HttpResponse(response, mimetype='application/json')
    else: # If the task must be started
    runFunTask = runFunctions.delay(shpId, codId, stepValues, bboxTuple);
    getRunFunStatus.delay(runFunTask)
    return render_to_response('tss/append_runCod.html',
                             {'runFunTask': runFunTask},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task()
def runFunctions(shpId, codId, stepValues, bboxTuple):
    # ... Code to define which functions to launch ...
    stepsToLaunch = [fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4, fun5]
    chainId = chain(stepsToLaunch).apply_async()
    chainAsyncObjects = [node for node in reversed(list(nodes(chainId)))]

    current_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={'step':1, 'total':numSteps})

    for t in range(10800): # The same max duration of a celery task
        for i, step in enumerate(chainAsyncObjects):
            currStep = i+1
            if step.state == 'PENDING':
                current_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={'step':currStep, 'total':numSteps})
                break
            if step.state == 'SUCCESS':
                if currStep == numSteps:
                    current_task.update_state(state="SUCCESS", meta={'step':currStep, 'total':numSteps})
                    sleep(5) # Wait before stop this task, in order for javascript to get the result!
                    return

            if step.state == 'FAILURE':
                return
        sleep(1)
```

**cods.js**

```
function getProgressCod(taskId){
    var interval = 2000; // Perform ajax call every tot milliseconds

    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'runCod/',
            data:{'taskId': taskId,},
            success: function(response){},
        });
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code for `nodes()` in the line `chainAsyncObjects = [node for node in reversed(list(nodes(chainId)))]`?